# $(\frac{x +1}{x^{2/3}-x^{1/3}+1} -\frac{x+1}{x-x^{1/2}})^{10}$ which term doesn't contain ${x}$?

Tags: combinations

As I know  $T_{r+{1}}$=$C(n,r)$ 
I can't able to apply the formula for the Term which not contain $x$,which is applicable for this (${x +\frac{1}{x}})^n$
So, please help me to solve this problem . Any help will be appreciated

Comment: Replacing $x$ everywhere with $x^6$ shouldn't change the constant term, but it will get rid of all those fractional exponents, and may let you see some cancellations.

Comment: The first term simplifies to $x^{1/3} + 1$.  The second term cannot be simplified unless there is a sign error in the numerator or denominator (but not both).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming the expression is 
$$\left(\frac{x +1}{x^{2/3}-x^{1/3}+1} -\frac{x-1}{x-x^{1/2}}\right)^{10}$$

The first term can be simplified setting $x^{1/3}=z\to x=z^3$

$\dfrac{x +1}{x^{2/3}-x^{1/3}+1}=\dfrac{z^3+1}{z^2-z+1}=z+1=x^{1/3}+1$

The second term simplifies in a similar way $x^{1/2}=z\to x=z^2$

$\dfrac{x-1}{x-x^{1/2}}=\dfrac{z^2-1}{z^2-z}=1+\dfrac{1}{x^{1/2}}$

The original expression simplifies to 
$$\left(x^{1/3}+1-1-\dfrac{1}{x^{1/2}}\right)^{10}=\left(\sqrt[3]{x}-\frac{1}{\sqrt{x}}\right)^{10}$$

Thus the terms non containing $x$ are those who simplify the cube and square roots, that is the $+a^6b^4$ term whose coefficient is $+\dbinom{10}{6}=210$

Hope this is useful

Comment: Not leaving much for OP to do.